# Vertical centring rows in a table

Tags: longtable, tabu

I am terribly sorry for bothering again with a problem which is probably very simple. The first line of my marking scheme is not correctly centred and I cannot understand why. Besides, I have to put a phantom fraction to increase the height of the first row and I was wondering whether there is an orthodox way to get a first row with a bigger height. I tried reading the tabu user guide but I couldn't solve the problem. An editable source is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=2mm
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth
  {|*{2}{X[0.2 cp]|}X[2 lp]|X[2 lp]|X[0.5 cm]|}
\hline
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25}\bfseries Question} &
\cellcolor{gray!25} Generic scheme & 
\cellcolor{gray!25}
\phantom{$\dfrac{1}{1}$}
Illustrative scheme
\phantom{$\dfrac{1}{1}$} & \cellcolor{gray!25} Total Mark
\endhead\hline
1. & (a) & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\textbf{Ans.} \\
$5$ 
\end{minipage} & $3+2 = 5$ & \textbf{1} \cr
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Since the result seems work, I am appending the screen of my original document:

[image]

I am appending also the screen of this example: the vertical centring problem is present also in this minimal example.

[image]

As we can see from the picture, the last column has the title *Total Mark* which is not vertically centred.

Thank you very much indeed for any help you may give me.

Comment: This code yields a centred  first row for me. Note it's better to set the last column width to 0.4cm.

Comment: Is it? Mine is not! I will try to post a screen of my page to show the problem.

Comment: I get undefined commands error with your example.

Comment: Indeed! It is the \cellcolor which require the colour package. I am sorry: I copied the example from the original source but I forgot to remove useless elements like the cell color. I will edit immediately.

Comment: Just load `xcolor` with option `[table]`.